# How to get CPU temperature in PowerShell 5.1 Version?

Tags: powershell, cpu, temperature

I am trying to get CPU temperature by using Windows Powershell 5.1 by running the following code at the bottom but unfortunately my Powershell is not returning anything. I am wondering what code should I put in the Windows Powershell 5.1 version in order to get the CPU temperature.

Code which I am using to get CPU temperature in Windows Powershell 5.1 version:

```
function Get-Temperature {
    $t = Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
    $returntemp = @()

    foreach ($temp in $t.CurrentTemperature)
    {


    $currentTempKelvin = $temp / 10
    $currentTempCelsius = $currentTempKelvin - 273.15

    $currentTempFahrenheit = (9/5) * $currentTempCelsius + 32

    $returntemp += $currentTempCelsius.ToString() + " C : " + $currentTempFahrenheit.ToString() + " F : " + $currentTempKelvin + "K"  
    }
    return $returntemp
}

Get-Temperature
```

Comment: [Maybe related](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/badf142e-2c34-4d6b-9362-d411e7f3b3a5/get-the-cpu-temperature-with-powershell?forum=ITCG).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Which one should I run ?  Majority of them there is returning an error:

`get-wmiobject : Not supported
At line:1 char:1
+ get-wmiobject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -namespace "root/wmi"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Is the problem related to the version which I am using ?

Comment: Bottom line of the accepted answer there is that you'll get an error if your BIOS doesn't support thermal sensors.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Right, Is that has to do anything with the version of powershell I am using ?

Comment: I'd doubt that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Also, one more last question, Is there any way we can read the hard drive smart status in powershell ? Like, any particular code for that ?

Comment: You might want to see what will come out of the CIM interface. `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_NumericSensor`

Comment: fyi your script runs fine in PowerShell 5.1 in an administrator session on a my laptop.

Comment: Are you running folding@home?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Open Hardware Monitor command line tool. 
[OpenHardwareMonitorReport.zip](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/files/1130239/OpenHardwareMonitorReport.zip)

More info here:https://superuser.com/a/1547638/589805

Comment: You can even get more recent version from this fork:
https://github.com/jochenwezel/openhardwaremonitor/releases